# Add image from generated buffered image as data record in jasper?

Tags: java

I'm totally new here in stackoverflow, so if there's anything wrong, i apologize...

I've been searching thoroughly at internet about how to add bufferedimage to jasperReport and haven't seem to find the answer...

So what I need is a custom record with generated bufferedimage dataset from java and put it into jasper report. As addition, i also need the pixel comparement between each inch / centimetres in jasperReport and bufferedImage pixels.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can specify that the BufferedImage use a parameter type of Image (off the top of my head) and pass the instance of the image via the Map parameter field. The key of the Map should be the same as the name of the parameter within the report

Comment: Yes i can specify it like that, but wont it loop the same image at the dataset? Because the image that i need is dynamic image dataset from a bufferedImage generation code for custom display and it contains different information...

Comment: What type of dataset are you using?

Comment: As referenced in http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/ i would like to try using custom data source with buffered image array type. Is it posible?

Comment: In theory, yes, I've used a `JRBeanCollectionDataSoruce`, which allows you to pass a `List` of "objects" to JasperReports, there shouldn't be any reason why one of the fields of that object can't be a `Image`...

Comment: I've tried that, but it only shows the String of the bufferedImage at the report smthing like " BufferedImage@13ef34f... " as I didn't find the right Expression class for this Datatype. Is there any way to get the right Expression class?

Comment: The I would assume that your expression is wrong or the expected field type is wrong